# Change css element on selected option

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to get my background color to change based off of a selected option. After they select to desired option nothing happens. Here is my code;

Html code;

```
<select id="importance" onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className" class="low">
    <option class="low" value="low">Low</option>
    <option class="medium" value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option class="high" value="high">High</option>
    <option class="urgentap" value="urgent">Urgent</option>
    </select>
```

Jquery;

```
   var projectCreate = $('#createP').on('click', function(){

    var name = $('.project-form input#name').val(),
        date = $('.project-form input#date').val(),
        time = $('.project-form input#time').val(),
        description = $('.project-form textarea#description').val(),

      importance = $('.project-form select#importance option:selected').val();
        if(importance == "Low")
$(".item").css('background','lightblue');
else if ($('#importance option:selected').text() == "Medium")
$(".item").css('background','yellow');
else if ($('#importance option:selected').text() == "High")
$(".item").css('background','orange');
else if ($('#importance option:selected').text() == "Urgent")
$(".item").css('background','red');
else
alert('test');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'xhr/new_project.php',
            data: {
                projectName: name,
                projectDescription: description,
                dueDate: date,
                time: time,
                status: importance
            },
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                if(response.error){

                    $( ".error" ).empty(),
                    $( ".error" ).fadeIn(),
                    $(".error").append('<h2 class="error-text">' + response.error + '</h2>').fadeIn(),
                    $( ".error" ).delay(1500),
                    $( ".error" ).fadeOut();


                }else{
                    loadApp();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
});
```

am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need onchange event for select element, i guess...

Comment: Might I suggest adding css classes for each of the `importance` cases and just applying the `importance` value as a class on `.item`?

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of extra craziness going on here that probably isn't helping your cause.

Let's start with detecting the change event for your select box. First we want unobtrusive code, so remove the JavaScript from your element:

```
<select id="importance" class="low">
    <option class="low" value="low">Low</option>
    <option class="medium" value="medium">Medium</option>
    <option class="high" value="high">High</option>
    <option class="urgentap" value="urgent">Urgent</option>
</select>
```

Then your jQuery code can do this:

```
$( "#importance" ).change(function() {
    var importance = $('option:selected', $(this)).val();
});
```

Next, I'd suggest including your background colours in a CSS class so that you don't need to work through which colour to apply individually. So create some classes like this:

```
.importance-low { background-color: lightblue; }
.importance-medium { background-color: yellow; }
.importance-high { background-color: orange; }
.importance-urgent { background-color: red; }
```

From there you can apply your class to any element as part of the `.change()` function above:

```
$('.item').removeClass('importance-low importance-medium importance-high importance-urgent').addClass('importance-' + importance);
```

That clears any previously-selected classes / values from your item and adds the newly-selected one.